# Conditional Logit using PROC MODEL

Tags: sas, time-series

I need to use distributed lag model (DLM) on a binary outcome. There is PDLREG but it can be applied to continuous outcomes. So it seems like the only way I can do this is using PROC MODEL and use %pdl macro. However I am using a 1:5 matched data and need to use conditional logit. How does one implement a conditional logit model in PROC MODEL? I am aware that conditional logit model can be implemented in PROC PHREG or PROC LOGISTIC. My need to use PROC MODEL is that I can use the pdl macro.

A sample code is given below for a continuous dependent variable using %pdl is given below.

```
    proc model data=pdl;
   parms int;                  /* declare the intercept parameter */
   %pdl( xpdl, 6, 4 )          /* declare the lag distribution */
   y = int + %pdl( xpdl, x );  /* define the model equation */
   fit y / list;               /* estimate the parameters */
run;
```

An unconditional logistic regression code in PROC MODEL would be

```
   proc model data=pdl;
   parms int;                  /* declare the intercept parameter */
   y=1/(1+exp(-(int+a*x)));        
   fit y / list;               /* estimate the parameters */
run;
```

I would like a similar code for conditional logit that would take into account the matched sets so that I can make use of the %pdl macro.